# When values is false show in msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to show message when some value is not meet criteria (boolean have false value.)
such as; if password is not long enough and uppercase is lower than 2 characters

now have 5 condition :

1. password must be longer than 10 character
2. Uppercase at least 1
3. lowercase at least 1

If not meet whatever conditions will show in msgbox

when value is false will show in msgbox

Comment: What is the question ? Please edit your question

Comment: I think he's asking how to make only certain lines in his `MsgBox` be included based on a boolean variable for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use multiple `If` to append message to string variable. At last, check if there is any content in string variable and show message box if there is content

```
strMessage = ""

If Not clength Then strMessage = strMessage & "- Please length must be equal or more than 10 characters " & vbNewLine
If Not cUp Then strMessage = strMessage & "- Upcase at least 2 characters" & vbNewLine
If Not cLow Then strMessage = strMessage & "- Lowercase at least 2 characters" & vbNewLine
If Not cNum Then strMessage = strMessage & "- Number at least 2 characters" & vbNewLine
If Not cSpe Then strMessage = strMessage & "- Special character at least 2 characters"

If Len(strMessage) > 0 Then MsgBox "Your password is weak, please revise as following:" & vbNewLine & strMessage
```